# Can't start Vite dev server on 443 without root, but native node server on 443 works without root

Tags: node.js, macos, http, vite

I was trying to use [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) in my project and wanted to start the local dev server on 443 port (MacOS) and I'm presented with the following error:

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:443
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1415:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1480:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1629:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:111:8)
```

Now as per *nix systems, I should get this error as ports < 1024 need root access.

**But my question is, how am I then able to listen on 443 port on a native node server?**

```js
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(443);
```

The code above works without any issue (also works with `https` module) on my system and **without root access**.
Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: This might be better asked at https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/